# Django using database without migration

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application running using MySQL database, and everything works fine.

For another part of the same application, I want to create a new Django application, implement database sharding, and have a separate database to store the tracking data and use the existing database (used by previous Django application) for authentication and other stuff.

But since I need to get data from the existing database using Django ORM, I created models with the required-only fields in the new application as well.

```py
# authentication.models.User

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField('email address', blank=True, unique=True)
    is_shared = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Is Shared User', default=False)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'authentication'
        managed = False
```

I want to use this model for authentication in the admin panel as well (the same is used in the existing application). But I do not want this new application to migrate changes to the master database, so added `managed=False` in the `Meta` class.

The `settings.py` file is

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Postgres partitioning
    "django.contrib.postgres",
    "psqlextra",

    ####################
    # Created apps
    ####################
    'tracking',
    'authentication',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'app.database_routers.tracking.TrackingRouter'
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': eval(os.environ.get('DATABASE_MASTER')),
    'database_tracking': eval(os.environ.get('DATABASE_TRACKING'))
}
```

where the `default` database has to be used for authentication and access to the admin panel. Migration should not write to this database as the migration should only be managed from the previous application to this database.

whereas `database_tracking` migration should run from this application. Therefore, I have written the database router `TrackingRouter` as

```py
class TrackingRouter:
    route_app_labels = {
        'tracking'
    }

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_tracking'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'database_tracking'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'database_tracking'
        return None
```

using this config, I want the migration to run for the models defined in the `tracking` application which should go to the `database_tracking` database.

When running `python manage.py migrate`, it gives `No migrations to apply.` but no table is created in the `database_tracking`.

While running `python manage.py migrate --database database_tracking` gives the following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_content_type" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_co...
                                                             ^
```

Please note, with this setup, I want to make the `default` database kind of read-only from this application and should be used for authentication and login to the admin panel, which the other database `database_tracking` should be used for read and write if the application label is `tracking`

Comment: What is your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby question updated with the list